# python syntax while using dict

Tags: python, syntax, coding-style

what is the correct way :

```
def my_func():
  return {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2}
```

or

```
def my_func():
  return
  {
    'key1': val1, 
    'key2': val2
  }
```

The second way seems more readable (especially when there is a lot of keys values, or nested objects) but I'm not sure the blank after return will work in every case

edit:

After some answers, I would suggest this :

```
def my_func():
  return {'key1': val1, 
          'key2': val2}
```

which seems to be the most consistent

Comment: There is no single correct way. I recommend using the most readable option. But apart from that, whatever works for you is fine...

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON; all I see is Python dictionaries being constructed. The second form returns None because the dictionary is defined on the next line, stand-alone and ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For short dictionaries, the first one is OK, the second one won't work as expected (returns `None`). For longer ones, I would prefer something like

```
def my_func():
    return {'key1': val1,
            'key2': val2,
            'key3': val3,
            'key4': val4,
           }
```

Comment: Why not start the contents of the dictionary/list/tuple from a newline?

Comment: @BasicWolf - because `return` alone in a line returns `None` ignoring what follows.

Comment: I mean `return { \n <contents here> \n }`

Comment: @BasicWolf - why not. Let's compare the upvotes for our answers to see what the population thinks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the same as @eumiro, but IMO starting the contents of a big dict/list/tuple from a newline makes the code a bit more readable:

```
def my_func():
    return {
        'key1': val1,
        'key2': val2,
        'key3': val3,
        'key4': val4,
    }
```

Comment: I would say there are more aesthetically appealing alternatives :)